# XSLT to search for an occurrence of child structure and create it if its missing

Tags: xslt

Given an input XML which looks like:

```
<foodGroup>
    <fruit>
        <label>Apple</label>
        <value>1</value>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <label>Banana</label>
        <value>2</value>
    </fruit>
    <vegetable/>
</foodGroup>
```

What would be the XSL transform which would check whether a fruit with label = 'Orange' and value = non 0 exists. And if its missing then adds the fruit/label and fruit/value structure to the output.

Something like this:

```
<foodGroup>
    <fruit>
        <label>Apple</label>
        <value>1</value>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <label>Banana</label>
        <value>2</value>
    </fruit>
    <fruit>
        <label>Orange</label>
        <value>3</value>
    </fruit>
    <vegetable />
</foodGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant test is `<xsl:if test="not(fruit[label = 'Orange' and value != 0])">`.

The following XSLT gives the result you asked for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foodGroup">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <xsl:if test="not(fruit[label = 'Orange' and value != 0])">
        <fruit>
          <label>Orange</label>
          <value><xsl:value-of select="count(fruit) + 1"/></value>
        </fruit>
      </xsl:if>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes that you want the fruit values to increase by one each time. If that's not a correct assumption, please specify what value you would like the added Orange to have.

Comment: Thanks, the test condition worked beautifully. And thanks a lot for providingthe whole style sheet - it actually helped me notice that some of my tests were behaving oddly because I had the version as 1.0 but was trying out xpath expressions from 2.0!

Comment: Seems in my attempt to make an example that would present my exact problem - I made it too simplistic. The inserted node ends up at the end of the document. However I'd like all my fruit node to appear together. Orange can occur before Apple or after Banana however it cannot occur after vegetable. I have been experimenting with matching for the Vegetable node and inserting the Orange before copying vegetable but I am running into too many errors. Can you suggest something ?

Comment: @Shilp: why don't you show the XSLT that you've been experimenting with, and we can take it from there.